# Can't deserialize a custom dictionary using IXmlSerializable.ReadXml

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a custom Dictionary that have string type for both keys and values.

I need to be able to write and read XML of this form:

```
<MyDict>
   <Key1>Value1</Key1>
   <Key2>Value1</Key2>
   <Key3>Value1</Key3>
</MyDict>
```

I've be able to generate the XML in the desired form:

```
public class SerializableListItem : System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<string, string>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (var key in this.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString(XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(key), this[key]);
        }
    }
```

However, I'm struggling to implement the `ReadXml` method. Right now, with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3525039/588868) (amongst other), I wrote :

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    this.Clear();
    reader.MoveToContent();
    while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
    {
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                reader.ReadEndElement();
                return;
            }

            reader.Read();
        }

        this.Add(XmlConvert.DecodeName(reader.LocalName), reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
        if (XmlNodeType.EndElement == reader.NodeType)
        {
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails with this error:

```
Run-time exception (line 31): There is an error in XML document (1, 63).

Stack Trace:

[System.Xml.XmlException: ReadElementContentAs() methods cannot be called on an element that has child elements. Line 1, position 63.]
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.SetupReadElementContentAsXxx(String methodName)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
   at SerializableListItem.ReadXml(XmlReader reader) :line 68
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, Boolean wrappedAny)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSerializableListItem.Read1_SerializableListItem()

[System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 63).]
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at Program.Main() :line 31
```

Here is a complete reproductible code : https://dotnetfiddle.net/vsnbIR

What did I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found another answer.

Here is the `ReadXml` implementation I used :

```
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            return;
        }

        reader.Read();
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    var key = reader.Name;
                    var value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    Add(key, value);
                    break;
                default:
                    // Comment, for instance.
                    reader.Read();
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Consume the EndElement
        reader.Read();
    }
```

It's working, but I don't understand precisely why.